# WifiNetworkSuggestion is undefined (Xamarin.android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Sorry this might be a stupid question.

I am now implementing an APP(through Xamarin) that use the WifiNetworkSuggestion.

I have "using Android.Net.Wifi" in my code but still not able to use WifiNetworkSuggestion.

How can I solve this problem?

```
using Android.Net.Wifi

.
.
.
 val wifiNetworkSuggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder() -> Here I got WiFiNetworkSuggestion is undefined
        .setSsid(ssid)
        .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
        .build()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you had added  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />` in AndroidManifest.xml . Some of the options on a `WifiNetworkSuggestion` requires you to request Fine Location permission in order to work. Make sure to consult the Android documentation to be sure.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSuggestion

Comment: Use `new  WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()....`.

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT. Thank you for your reply.
I have the permission. And this is not a runtime error.
The error appear during compile. Looks like the WifiNetworkSuggestion is not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might have same problem with me.

My condition is:

1. Using visual studio 2017. Found out that I can't target to android 10.
2. Install visual studio 2019. Open same project. Found out that API won't work.

Solution:

This was due to the mono.android was still target to 2017's folder(Only support to API 28).

Delete the Mono.android in current project. Target the Mono.android in Visual 2019 folder(Select API 29).

This works for me.